# Isomorphism Theorems for Lie Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, vector-space-isomorphism

So I stumbled across the isomorphism theorems for Lie Algebras which are as follows:

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be Lie algebras, $\phi$ : $L_1$ $\rightarrow$ $L_2$ a homomorphism of Lie algebras and $I$,$J$ ideals of a Lie algebra $L$ $\Rightarrow$

1.)  $L_1/$Ker($\phi$) $\cong$ im($\phi$)

2.) $(I+J)/J$ $\cong$ $I/(I \cap J)$\

3.)  if $I \subseteq J$ $\Rightarrow$ $J/I$ is an ideal of $L/I$ and $(L/I)/(J/I)$ $\cong$ $L/J$

That these theorems hold for vector spaces and their subspaces is already known.I read somewhere that because the canonical projection

$\pi$: $L \rightarrow L/I$, $x \mapsto x+I$ is a homomorphism of Lie algebras that these theorems are also true for Lie algebras.

I don't see how we can conclude that from $\pi$ being a homomorphism.

Comment: These are general facts in universal algebra: their analogs hold for any algebraic structure.

Comment: yes, but I am just trying to understand why they hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:** The crucial thing for $\pi$ being Lie algebra homomorphism, is  that the induced Lie bracket $[x+I, \, y+I] :=[x,y] +I$ on $L/I$ is *well defined*.

For the first isomorphism theorem, we obtain a vector space isomorphism $\phi':L_1/\ker\phi\to {\rm im}\, \phi$, and since $\ker\phi$ is an ideal, $L_1/\ker\phi$ is a Lie algebra, and by construction $\phi'$ carries the induced Lie bracket of $L_1/\ker\phi$ to the one of $L_2$, so $\phi'$ is also a Lie algebra isomorphism.

The other statements follow from the first isomorphism theorem in the usual way.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I have thought about your hint but I don't see what you mean

Comment: It's mainly a hint for how to see $\pi:L\to L/I$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism. If that's clear, the usual proofs of the statements will just work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Indeed it doesn't seem to be a direct consequence of $\pi$ being a homomorphism, but can be done in a similar manner.

Comment: So when you say that by construction $\phi'$ carries the induces Lie bracket of $L_1/$ker$\phi$ to the one of $L_2$ you mean that if we have $[x,y]+$ker$\phi$  then $\phi'$ will send it to $\phi'([x,y])$?

Comment: Yes, explicitly $\phi'([x+I,\, y+I]) = \phi'([x,y]+I)=\phi([x,y])=[\phi(x),\,\phi(y)]=[\phi'(x+I),\,\phi'(y+I)]$ where $I=\ker\phi$.